# Riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> In my youth I was such a wiry square.
>
> Now I've started to select some better friends, and
>
> I've really taken shape,
>
> and will live a longer life.
>
> At least people have always played with me.
>
> I got so much joy, and started to stick
>
> with some nicknames like fatty,
>
> I used to be a real duke!

What am I?

Comment: Sounds like some arcade game to me, yet i haven't figure out which

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a

> video game controller.

In my youth I was such a wiry square.

> Old controllers had wires, and were more squarely shaped (e.g. NES).

Now I've started to select some better friends, and

> References to "start" and "select" buttons? "Better friends" may refer to the appearance of more buttons, or better (i.e. more advanced) consoles/games.

I've really taken shape,

> Now, controllers are more shapely.

and will live a longer life.

> Better batteries and rechargeable packs = longer life.

At least people have always played with me.

> They sure have!

I got so much joy, and started to stick

> Joystick.

with some nicknames like fatty,
I used to be a real duke!

> Previous Xbox controller iterations have been given nicknames "Duke" and "Fatty".

Comment: ----- Well Done!